# Consultar si elemento existe en la base de datos php

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

estoy tratando de que cuando el usuario salga del foco de un input text se muestre si ese valor ya existe en la base de datos o no, pero siempre me arroja que existe. (La peticion pasa por un controlador pero lo omito aca), Siento que el error debe estar en la consulta a la base de datos

**Codigo Javascript que manda el valor usando AJAX**

```
$("#ordenTrabajo").blur(function() {
var orden = document.getElementById("ordenTrabajo").value;
if (!(orden == "")) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "views/ajax/OIT.php",
        method: "GET",
        data: { funcion: "funcion3", "or": orden },
        async: false,
        //dataType: "json",
        success: function(respuesta) {
            if (respuesta == "existe") {
                alert("Existe");
            } else {
                alert("No Existe");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

});
**Archivo php a donde llega el AJAX**

```
<?php

require_once "../../controllers/OIT.php";
require_once "../../models/OIT.php";


#CLASES
#**********************************************************************

class Ajax{


   #COMPROBAR SI ORDEN EXISTE
    #******************************************************************

    public $ordenTrabajo;

    public function comprobarOrden(){

       $datos = array("orderJob" => $this -> ordenTrabajo);
       $respuesta = GestorOIT::obtenerOrdenController($datos);
       echo $respuesta;

   }


#OBJETOS
#************************************************************************

//Comprobar que la dato no venga vacio
if(isset($_GET['funcion']) && !empty($_GET['funcion'])) {
    $funcion = $_GET['funcion'];

    //En función del parámetro que nos llegue ejecutamos una función u otra
    switch($funcion) {
        case 'funcion1': 
            $a = new Ajax();
            $a -> gestorViasAjax();
            break;
        case 'funcion2': 
           $b = new Ajax();
           $b -> gestorDestinosAjax();
            break;
        case 'funcion3': 
           $c = new Ajax();
           $c -> ordenTrabajo = $_GET["or"];
           $c -> comprobarOrden();
           break;
    }
}


?>
```

**Modelo donde se ejecuta la consulta**

```
public function obtenerOrdenModel($datos, $tabla){
        $stmt = Conexion::conectar() -> prepare("SELECT n_lote FROM cajas WHERE ordenTrabajo=:orden");
         $stmt -> bindParam(":orden", $datos["orderJob"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
         $stmt->execute();
         $stmt -> fetch();
         if($stmt!=""){
            return "existe";
         }else{
            return "no";
         }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final logre solucionarlo cambiado esta linea

```
if($stmt!="")
```

por esta

```
if($stmt->rowCount()>0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Creo que el error esta en esta comprobación:

```
$stmt -> fetch();
if($stmt!=""){
  return "existe";
}else{
  return "no";
}
```

Al ser `$stmt`un objeto, no creo que sea lo mejor compararlo con un string vacío. Para saber si existe podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```
  $stmt = Conexion::conectar() -> prepare("SELECT 1 FROM cajas WHERE ordenTrabajo=:orden");
  $stmt -> bindParam(":orden", $datos["orderJob"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $stmt->execute();
  $count = $stmt->fetchColumn();
  if($count > 0){
      return "existe";
  }else{
      return "no";
  }
```

o directamente

```
if(!$stmt->fetchColumn()){
    return "existe";
}else{
    return "no";
}
```

Notesé, que la query la he cambiado por un 1, ya que no necesitas mas para saber si existe o no.